# Facebook Live API Not Announcing Videos

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-live-api

Using Graph I've created a page in PHP to automatically create "scheduled" live videos for our page. I have permissions correct, at least according to their documentation (`publish_actions, manage_pages, publish_pages, public_profile`).

I have followed the documentation located [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/videos/live-video/production-broadcasts#create). It creates the "scheduled" live video correctly. The video shows up under publishing tools in my pages manager as well. But the announcement on the page isn't there, it should be.

If I follow the normal procedure to create a scheduled live video from publisher tools, it schedules, then creates the announcement on my page timeline.

These are the key/value pairs I am sending:

```
$params = array(
    'access_token' => '{HIDDEN}',
    'planned_start_time' => $startTime,
    'status' => 'SCHEDULED_UNPUBLISHED',
    'title' => $dateTitle
);
```

And I am posting to `/{PAGE_ID}/live_videos` as per the documentation, using their SDK for PHP.

The code has to be correct that I am sending since it creates the scheduled video in the publisher tools, and no permission errors or other are returned to me. It returns a video ID actually, so I know that part works.

If I query, in the graph explorer, my pages `live_videos` feed, I get all videos I have streamed correctly, and at the top my newest one with the status `SCHEDULED_UNPUBLISHED`. This status is the same as all the other videos published from publisher tools.

So to summarize, it creates the video fine, I have even tried streaming to the stream url, it works. I can even view the video afterward. But it won't publish a scheduled video announcement to my timeline via the API, only the publisher tools page.

Comment: can you please share the any help , i just create create secure_stream_url, but not know how to stream from camera , any help.

Answer (score -1):

I have not used the live video API myself but from reading the document the one possibility is when you were testing, your planned start time is less than 10 minutes from now, and the announcement just get deleted straight away?

Comment: Can you please provide a link to this part of the documentation and quote the part in your answer? Thanks!

Comment: You will get #200 error in that case. I mean if your ["planned_time" - now] less than 10 mins. Seems like the problem is in the privacy status.